# Measuring Performance Kafka Streams with JConsole

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, jconsole

I've seen that with JConsole it's possible to have information for each node of the topology such as process rate, punctuate rate, forward rate etc. I would like to know how long it takes a message to be processed, that is from when the first node (the producer) sends the message to when it leaves the last node and is written in the topic. Is it possible to know this with JConsole or should I follow another way?

Comment: If you just want to track time, look at using distributed tracing with the Brave Kafka library

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I tried but I can't use this library. Is it the same if manually, for each node, I add to the record the milliseconds through ZonedDateTime.now().toInstant().toEpochMilli()  and then calculate the difference between the last node and the first in the topology?

Comment: As long as you have consistent timezones between records, it might work